# Event when Outlook Web Add-In closes

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Do we have any event that gets fired before the Outlook Add-In closes? Like we have OnReady which gets fired when Add-In is triggered in case of Contextual Add-In.

Comment: "Do we have any event that gets fired before the Outlook Add-In closes" : Do you mean when we close the taskPane?

Comment: No. The event that fires when we close the contextual Add-In window by clicking outside the Add-In window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible today. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page.
It looks like the feature you want has been requested by others already. Please upvote the [existing request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/17572624-need-to-have-an-onclose-event-for-the-task-pane-or). Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.